# Why should length of the array be stored in selection sort algorithm?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, selection-sort

The algorithm code from Grokking algorithm book:

```
const findSmallestIndex = (array) => {
  let smallestElement = array[0]; // Stores the smallest value
  let smallestIndex = 0; // Stores the index of the smallest value

  for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < smallestElement) {
      smallestElement = array[i];
      smallestIndex = i;
    }
  }

  return smallestIndex;
};

// 2. Sorts the array
const selectionSort = (array) => {
  const sortedArray = [];
  const length = array.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // Finds the smallest element in the given array 
    const smallestIndex = findSmallestIndex(array);
    // Adds the smallest element to new array
    sortedArray.push(array.splice(smallestIndex, 1)[0]);
  }

  return sortedArray;
};

console.log(selectionSort([5, 3, 6, 2, 10])); // [2, 3, 5, 6, 10]
```

The problem is in the function `selectionSort`, storing the array length in the variable wes necessary to make it work correctly and this one i couldn't understand, i tried to not store the length in a variable:

```
const selectionSort = (array) => {
  const sortedArray = [];


  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // Finds the smallest element in the given array 
    const smallestIndex = findSmallestIndex(array);
    // Adds the smallest element to new array
    sortedArray.push(array.splice(smallestIndex, 1)[0]);
  }

  return sortedArray;
};

console.log(selectionSort([5, 3, 6, 2, 10])); // [2, 3, 5]
```

I guessed that the problem may be the  `splice` method because it reduces the length every time in the loop  but i think the index is not important here, so it may not be be the problem!

Comment: Your guess is correct. Also, that's a wasteful implementation of a not-very-good algorithm, it's unfortunate that it's from an educational resource.

Comment: You mean that code is bad, it is from grokking algorithm book, one of the best reviewed books in algorithms!

Comment: Using `.splice()` adds an extra inefficiency, as that requires copying the tail end of the source array each time.

Comment: I still can't relate .. why splice do that in this case, i think splice reduce the array every time but i think this is not important since the index doesn't make much difference in this case!

Comment: How would you write a function to remove an element from the middle of an array? You have to copy every element from that position back one position. That's an O(n) process.

Comment: @Pointy Using selection sort adds inefficiency, because it's an O(n^2) algorithm where an O(n log n) algorithm could solve the same problem. The particular way of implementing selection sort is not so important, and I guess this is just for a learning exercise.

Comment: @kaya3 I know that, but it's from a *textbook*.  There's no reason to teach people questionable coding practices.

Comment: @Pointy `array.splice` is the standard way of removing an element from an array by index in Javascript. Is there a more efficient way of removing an element by index, or are you saying the algorithm should not work by removing-by-index?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying; look at the answer I posted. It is unnecessary to splice out an element at all. A simple swap will suffice.

Comment: @Pointy Your answer implements the standard, in-place selection sort algorithm; the algorithm here is an out-of-place version which works by iteratively finding and removing the minimum from one array and pushing it to the other. It can be reasonably described as a form of selection sort since it works conceptually the same except the unsorted and sorted parts are kept in different arrays. It is perfectly reasonable to teach this version as well as the standard version. If an algorithms textbook only showed the most efficient solution for each problem, it would not be a good textbook.

Comment: It's also pedagogically worthwhile to study the out-of-place selection sort algorithm as a precursor to out-of-place heapsort, which also works by iteratively finding-and-removing the minimum element, but does that operation in O(log n) time instead of O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is removing the element from the original array, so on each iteration, `i++` increases `i` and also `splice` decreases `array.length`. That means `i` and `array.length` get closer together by 2 each time instead of by 1, so the loop only iterates half as many times as you want it to. That means you only sort half of the elements into `sortedArray`.

By copying `const length = array.length;` first, the variable `length` is not changed inside the loop, so the `i++` makes `i` closer to `length` on each iteration by 1, so the number of iterations is the original array length, and every element gets sorted.

As a side note, your algorithm sorts into a new array, but leaves the original array empty. That's probably never what you want; a sorting algorithm should either sort the array in-place (leaving the original array in sorted order), or return a new sorted array (leaving the original array unchanged). You could fix this by making a copy of `array` at the start of your function, so the algorithm destroys the copy instead of the original.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this here for the sole reason that the posted implementation, apparently from an algorithms text, is needlessly overcomplicated and inefficient as well.

```
function selectionSort(array) {
  function smallestIndex(start) {
    let si = start;
    for (let i = start + 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
      if (array[i] < array[si])
        si = i;
    }
    return si;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let index = smallestIndex(i), t;
    // swap value into current slot
    t = array[index];
    array[index] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Here, the `smallestIndex()` function is enhanced to take a starting position as a parameter. Thus it finds the index of the smallest value in the *remainder* of the array. On the first iteration, that'll be the smallest value in the whole array. That value is swapped with whatever is at the current starting point, so after that first time through the main loop position 0 in the array is the smallest value in the whole array.

On the next iteration, the search for the index starts at 1, so that process will find the *second smallest* value from the original array, and swap that into position 1.

The process continues through the array. Note that no new arrays are constructed, and there are no calls to linear-time Array methods.